# Manhwa/manhua where the youngest son becomes powerful and is sent to an academy where he is tested by clones of a summoned white tiger

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I read this manhwa a while ago where the youngest son is bullied by his elder siblings. A soul from past reincarnated and he gets power. He is recognized and the father (also patriarch) gives him his sword. He is sent to an academy/school to train to some castle. Before entering the castle, he is tested by clones of (summoned) white tiger.

This might be the one where the main character is originally born with just one hand and is bullied, but later defeats the prince and is killed and later reincarnated.

Answer (score 4):

This is a korean webtoon called [Standard of Reincarnation](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/egniw80/standard-of-reincarnation).

Featuring:

- The protagonist, Daven, was a one-armed swordsman who died and reincarnated into a young boy's body in the far future.
- Daven the boy's body wins recognition from the family's patriarch and is given a unique rapier as a reward.
- When sent to the Crimson Fortress academy, he faces a number of illusory clones of white tigers, in chapter 25:

[image]